# Can I still get the back piece from Secret of Southsun achievements?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I started the achievement with my lv56 Mesmer a while back, then finals happened and I don't have a computer that can play the game on for the time being. Will I be able to log back in and complete the achievement if I still have the plant seeking item in my inventory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the [Fervid Censor](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Fervid_Censer) can no longer be obtained because that part of the living story is over.

Edit: Since the achievements UI was changed, none of the "Historical" achievements can be completed.

There is a similar option back piece though. The Cutthroat Politics living story introduced a back piece with a similar appearance to the Fervid Censor, called the [Desert Rose](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Desert_Rose), which can be purchased on the trading post.

Comment: To be honest the Living Story is so bad because it cheapens holiday events, because now we get events every month :(

Comment: That sucks. Not liking the temporary aspect of some of the items in the Living story, I guess it gives them some prestige. I wish they would add the living story as side quests in our personal story.